# Convert integer to ITime?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking into using the new `data.table` date and time formats. Since `ITime` is stored as an integer under the hood (number of seconds since midnight):

```
x <- as.ITime( "10:25:00" )
i <- as.integer( x )
i
[1] 37500
```

It seems like it should be easy enough to convert an integer (assuming it's less than 24*60*60) to `ITime`, but I'm not finding how:

```
as.ITime( i )
Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, ...) : 'origin' must be supplied

as( i, "ITime" )
Error in as(i, "ITime") : 
  no method or default for coercing “integer” to “ITime”
```

Providing an origin (which I gather gets passed to `as.POSIX...`) does help, but even then it only gives the right value (for my locale anyway) if you also specify `tz` as "UTC":

```
as.ITime( i, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00" )
[1] "20:25:00"

as.ITime( i, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC" )
[1] "10:25:00"

# note that the date seems necessary but irrelevant here
as.ITime( i, origin = "2000-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC" )
[1] "10:25:00"
```

What I'm talking about is something similar to what I sometimes use with `chron::times`:

```
x <- chron::times( "10:25:00" )

n <- as.numeric( x )
n
[1] 0.4340278

chron::times( n )
[1] 10:25:00
```

Is a similar (except using integers instead of numbers/doubles/floats) method available with the `ITime` class?

Note I'm aware of the same "origin required" issue with `IDate`, `Date`, etc., but that makes more sense to me since `origin="1970-01-01"` is a lot less of a robust standard compared with using "midnight" as an origin for time (I use some data sources with different ideas on which date should be called the "origin").

Comment: setattr class should do it.

Comment: Indeed it does, thanks Frank! Please feel free to turn your comment into an answer if you'd like, and I'll accept it.

Comment: How would you achieve that with `setattr`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg `setattr( 1:10, "class", "ITime" )` for example, does essentially what I want to achieve. I'd love to hear another way if you have one though.

Comment: Ahh nice, didn't think a function can serve as a value and the name is actually being parsed that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(int = 37500L)
DT[, setattr(int, "class", "ITime")]

#         int
# 1: 10:25:00
```

or

```
int = 37500L
setattr(int, "class", "ITime")

# "10:25:00"
```

Comment: Is this faster than `as.ITime`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico `as.ITime(37500L) # error`? It should be pretty fast since it's just adding an attribute to the vector and so shouldn't cost more on a longer vector.

Comment: hehe i meant `as.ITime(37500, origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00', tz = 'UTC')`... it looks like it should be faster to use `setattr`, but on the other hand, I feel like `as.ITime` should be sped up to the extent possible in that case